# Analytics usage report timezone

Tags: powershell, 2016, statistics, popularity-trends

We are using SP2016 enterprise. In Site settings -> Popularity and Search Reports, we can download the usage report. The report is generated based on GMT 0 timezone but all my users are located in GMT+8. Therefore click rate at Saturday morning are counted as Friday's.

Am I able to generate the same report using custom timezone? If not, could I query the numbers using PowerShell with specific timezone?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing timezone for site using Regional Settings?

https://sharepointmaven.com/sharepoint-time-zone/

Comment: Yes. The timezone are correct set at +8